# Google sign in without play services

Tags: android, authentication, unity-game-engine, oauth

in my game i want to implement Google Sign in button, but i don't want to use any of GPG services. I just need an account information from google user. Any tips how to do this? I've found a lot of articles about using Google Play Game services in Unity app, but nothing about it.

Comment: You only need `compile "com.google.android.gms:play-services-auth:10.2.6"`.

Comment: A sample https://github.com/googlesamples/google-signin-unity If you already haven't visited it .

Comment: Idk how did i miss that. Thank you very much!

Comment: If your problem is resolved then answer your own question with explanation and complete the quest !!

Comment: I've successfuly implement this plugin in my project but now i have another issues. when i select account, i have empty auth code and email. Other fields is correct. What is the problem?